# only 1 out of 4 <hr/> tags not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have a View which displays a list of school model information. I have broken it down into various sections using `<hr/>` tags. Although for some reason the 3rd `<hr/>` tag (with the title "Additional School Details") is not displaying while the rest are. Can anyone see why this is?

The other 3 `<hr/>` tags are displaying perfectly and I can not see what is causing the 3rd one not to display

EDIT: it seems like if i zoom in the 3rd hr tag displays. Why is this?

delete.cshtml

```
<br />
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this Booking entry?</h3>
<h4>@Model.OfficialSchoolName</h4>
<br />
<hr />

<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <h4>School Contact Details</h4>
        <br />

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RollNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RollNumber)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OfficialSchoolName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OfficialSchoolName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TeacherName)
        </dt>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrincipalName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PrincipalName)
        </dd>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TeacherName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address1)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address1)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address2)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address2)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address3)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address3)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address4)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address4)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Eircode)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Eircode)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.County)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </dd>

        <hr />
        <h4>Camp Details</h4>
        <br />

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LecturerName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LecturerName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartTime)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartTime)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndTime)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EndTime)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surveys)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Surveys)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClassGroups)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClassGroups)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Topics)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Topics)
        </dd>

        <hr />
        <h4>Additional School Details</h4>
        <br />

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocalAuthority)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LocalAuthority)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AcademicYear)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AcademicYear)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DeisSchool)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeisSchool)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SchoolGender)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SchoolGender)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PupilAttendanceType)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PupilAttendanceType)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IrishClassification)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IrishClassification)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GaeltachtArea)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GaeltachtArea)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeePayingSchool)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FeePayingSchool)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Religion)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Religion)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OpenClosedStatus)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpenClosedStatus)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalGirls)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalGirls)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalBoys)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalBoys)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalPupils)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TotalPupils)
        </dd>

        <hr />
        <h4>School Coordinates</h4>
        <br />

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.X)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.X)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Y)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Y)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITMEast)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ITMEast)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITMNorth)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ITMNorth)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Latitude)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Latitude)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Longitude)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Longitude)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of factors, your monitor resolution, your zoom, hr pixel size, color of the line, and etc. An alternative to try is use `border-top` or `border-bottom` css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrity of this structure should remain untouched. You are putting heading elements (and `<br />` elements) inside this structure and it is not sustainable. I am not sure if you have css affecting on your line height or something that zooming make effect on seeing it or not but nonetheless changing the integrity of the below structure is not wise:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
    <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

If you want cross browser support you need to only have `<dt>` and `<dd>` as direct children of the `<dl>`

Please read this: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-dl-element.html)

In writing a good html code you should always consider the nature of elements:
`<br />` tag is an inline tag while `<h1>` is block-level tag as well as `<dl><dt><dd>`
You should not use inline level tags to separate block level tags. You might get results this way but is is not sustainable and not every browser reacts the same to this.

You can use inline elements inside the `<td>` and `<dd>`. Elements like: `<a>`,`<b>`,`<i>`, `<img>`,`<span>`, and so on ... ,which have effects on text or image, can be used inside those mentioned elements but NOT directly inside `<dl>`.

You can still use css and class to make the visual effect you need.

Comment: No Problem. Happy to help ;)

Comment: You still can use css and class to make some of the elements bold and with bigger size fonts and paddings though.